# How to search oracle db timezone in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, dual-table

I want to connect to oracle database in my ruby on rails application and i need to get db timezone with sql "select dbtimezone from dual"

I have the code

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :bug

  def self.get_db_timezone
    return self.find_by_sql("select dbtimezone from dual")[0]
  end
end
```

When i call

```
ap Bug.get_db_timezone
```

I got string printed in my console

```
#<Bug:0x0000002339df28> {}
```

Which means i got nothing.

I have no way to get dual information from oracle in my RoR application.
Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by myself by using this-

```
db_timezone = self.find_by_sql("SELECT DBTIMEZONE tz FROM DUAL")[0].tz
```